# Moving Drupal database from MySQL to Oracle

Tags: 7, migrations, database

I've developed a website with Drupal 7 running on standard PHP/MySQL server. Now there's a need to move it to server with Oracle database. While I managed to set up testing environment with a fresh Drupal 7 install and all my modules, to check if they are working with Oracle DB, now all data from original development version needs to be moved to new server.
First option was to use Oracle SQL Developer "Migrate" function, but I ended up manually copying tables from repository to Oracle DB and in the end it failed to function.
Next thing I tried some migration tools. DBTNG migrator failed, because production server has no MySQL or SQLite extensions, so it was impossible to import anything from original database. Backup and Migrate module works only with MySQL. Other modules were migrating limited number of data types or didn't support i18n.
There's a third option of manually recreating all content types, menus, taxonomy, views and other elements, but in the end it would be very convenient to have a system for migration from MySQL to Oracle database.
What needs to be migrated: custom content, fields, blocks, menus, taxonomy, views and all translations.
Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this task? Preferably using open and free software, but commercial products are an alternative, if they work fast and efficiently.

Comment: You may want to consider posting this to http://dba.stackexchange.com to see if there is a non-Drupal method that will work.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you'll have a bumpy ride with Oracle since it's not an officially supported Drupal database, which means modules such as Views have no Oracle specific code for dealing with cross-db incompatibilities such as date handling.

Answer (score 1):

This may be another long shot and I certainly haven't tried it myself, but assuming that the Features module works on a fresh install on top of Oracle, you may be able use it to export your content types, menus, and views from the MySQL-based site. The [Features extra](http://drupal.org/project/features_extra) module might allow you to export the taxonomy too.

You could then add the Services module on the MySQL site to serve up content to either the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module or maybe the [Web service client](http://drupal.org/project/wsclient) module on the Oracle-based site.

Another caveat is that I don't know how well either of these steps would handle the i18n.

Good luck!

Comment: Features sounds like a good way to export content types. You could also look at http://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d for migrating content from one Drupal site to another.